# Group by rather than where select in?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have an SQL statement  that returns the rows I need based upon a where clause that filters my customerID where they became a customer in a specific month.  What I need to do is run this per month for the last 40 months but currently this means running the SQL 40 times and changing the date filters.

Does anyone know how I could get the SQL to group this info rather than filter on the date as this will take me about 15 hours to do as there are 50 stores to run this query against.

There's my SQL:

```
select count(customerID), date_format(date_time, '%b %Y'), actionID
from transactions

where   date_time = (select min(date_time) 
        from transactions as T 
        where actionID=2
        and date_time > '2010-07-01 00:00:00'
        and  T.customerID = transactions.customerID)
        and store_id= 1

and     customerID IN 
        (
        SELECT customerID
        FROM    transactions
        where   store_id = 1
        and     actionID in (1,6)
            and date_time > '2010-07-01 00:00:00' 
        and     date_time < '2010-08-01 00:00:00'
        )


group by date_format(date_time, '%b %Y')
order by  date_time
```

The date I'm currently filtering '2010-07-01 00:00:00' is the one I really meed to group by rather than filter so I get a value for each month from July 2009 to Oct 2012.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks and regards
Richard

Answer (score 0):

You seem to already know exactly what you need. You want a column that truncates the date_time to the month, then you want to group by that column.

To truncate a datetime to a first of the month isn't that difficult.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), date_time, 120) + '-1' as DATETIME)
```

So you either need an initial query that does the date transformation above or add a calculated column to the table that does it, then you group by this 'first of the month' column.